# Unix sort function that sorts a space delimited txt file according to specific column by ASCII value

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix, ascii

I have tried to come up with this answer but everything I try does not work.
My code below is what I have come up with:

```
sort -k$field_number "$1".db > temp.txt && cp temp.txt "$1.db"
```

Shouldn't this line of code sort the .db file by ASCII value (the sort function should sort by ASCII by default?). In the code, field_number corresponds to the column I wish to sort the lines of the file by. When I use my code to format the file (where I am sorting by column 2), I get the output below.

Textfile (the .db file) format:

```
a 5 5 5
Green 72 72 72
Smith 84 72 93
Jones 85 73 94
z 9 9 9
Ford 92 64 93
Miller 93 73 87
bobua che Apple Xor
```

Comment: To help us to help you, how would you like to see this file?
Looking the second column, we have numbers and letters, what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Oh, does sort not delimit by spaces automatically? If so, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is with your collection. Try this please:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -n --ignore-case -k$field_number "$1".db > temp.txt && cp temp.txt "$1.db"
```